# Am I a dependent or can I claim an exemption for myself?

Tags: united-states, taxes, education, dependents

I am a university student who is currently working on filing my 2017 federal income taxes.

My parents can no longer claim me as a dependent because they did not support me over 50% in 2017. However, my college tuition, room, and board (over 50% of my support) were paid of a 529 funded by my grandparents.

On the tax form, I am wondering whether I have to check the box “I can be claimed as a dependent on someone else’s return”. While I believe I cannot be claimed on anyone else’s return, I didn’t pay half of my own support.

Whether or not I can check this box makes a very large difference in the size of my return. Should I to check the box or not?

Comment: Did you live with your grandparents at all in 2017 when you weren't in school?

Comment: @BenMiller not at all

Comment: Did you earn more than $4,050 in 2017?  Also, did you live with your parents when not in school?

Comment: @HartCO Yes and yes

Comment: Sorry, and you're under 24?

Comment: @HartCO Yes I am

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if they are currently contributing to a 529 plan that you are benefiting from, they might want to look at the benefits of paying tuition directly rather than contributing to 529 plan.

Comment: He said 529 was funded by grandparents.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Right, but if they are actively contributing for OP while distributions are being made, it can be better to help by directly paying tuition or gifting to the parents instead of making additional contributions to the plan.

Comment: You got me. There are nuances to this that are beyond me. In 2018 there are no exemptions. Would you still say the parents could benefit from claiming the child?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like your parents can claim you as a dependent. The test isn't if they provided 50% of your support, but that you didn't provide more than 50% of your own support.

The instructions for [Form 1040, line 6c](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm140365751100272) list the following requirements for a qualifying child:

> A qualifying child is a child who:
>
> - Is your son, daughter, stepchild, foster child, brother, sister, stepbrother, stepsister, half brother, half sister, or a descendant of
>     any of them (for example, your grandchild, niece, or nephew)
> - Was under age 19 at the end of 2017 and younger than you (or your spouse,  if filing jointly) or Under age 24 at the end of 2017, a
>     student  (defined later), and younger than you (or your spouse, if
>     filing  jointly) or Any age and permanently and totally disabled
>     (defined  later)
> - Who didn't provide over half of his or her own support for 2017 (see Pub. 501)
> - Who isn't filing a joint return for 2017 or is filing a joint return  for 2017 only to claim a refund of withheld income tax or
>     estimated  tax paid (see Pub. 501 for details and examples)
> - Who lived with you for more than half of 2017. If the child  didn't live with you for the required time, see Exception to time  lived with
>     you, later.

They don't consider being away at college to break the residency test, that's part of the "Exception to time lived with you" section.

Edit: Updated to better source mentioned by @prl

Comment: You _could_ argue that if the OP was the beneficiary of the 529 that he _did_ provide his own support since the 529 is legally his to use as he sees fit.

Comment: @DStanley Don't think the IRS agrees with that argument, unless the student funded the 529 account. Source of funds seems the primary consideration for support.